# How to add elements from response after Backbone fetch into another fetch

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, handlebars.js

```
 var ChannelStatsView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: "#id-channel-stats",
  initialize: function() {

    var _this = this;

    this.modelChannelList = new channelListModel();
    this.modelChannelStats = new channelStatsModel();
    this.channelstatsCollection = new channelStatsCollection();

    this.channelNames = [];
    this.listOfObjects = [];

    this.modelChannelList.fetch({
      success: function(model, response, options) {
        model.set();
        _this.formatChannelIds();

      },

      error: function(model, xhr, options) {

      }
    });
  },
  formatChannelIds: function() {

    _this = this;
    _.filter(_this.modelChannelList.toJSON(), function(channelObj) {
      if (channelObj['isactive'] == true) {
        _this.updateStats(channelObj['id'], channelObj['name']);
      }
    });
  },

  updateStats: function(id, name) {

    var _this = this;

    _this.modelChannelStats.fetch({
      data: {
        channel: id
      },
      processData: true,
      success: function(model, response, options) {

        _this.response = response;
        _this.listOfObjects.push(_this.response.records[0]);
        _this.channelNames.push(name);
      }
    }).done(function(model, response, options) {
      _this.render();
    });
  },
  render: function() {

    var _this = this;

    if (_this.listOfObjects.length == 0) {

    } else {
      _this.template = channelTemplate;
      _this.$el.html(_this.template({
        orderData: _this.listOfObjects,
        channelNames: _this.channelNames
      }));
    }
  }
});
```

In my code i am taking the response from one model.fetch query i.e `this.modelChannelList` and getting all the active id's then supplying it to another fetch to get the response i know this solution is really bad can someone help me how to make it faster and effective.

I am considering using `Promises`

Comment: Is it not possible to do check for active id's and then fetch the response in one call at the server side itself or is it like you are querying two different data sources and  hence, need to make two calls?

Comment: each of the id's has a different data that i need to display so i can't call together.

Comment: They are two different calls and i have two different api's

Comment: Can you post the json structure of the models : ChannelList and ChannelStats.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue you need to deal with here is the number of fetch requests that you are making. Promises are cool so I've included that too. Here's what I recommend you do:

**1)** Update your model class to assign the fetch function as a deferred

```
var channelListModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        // Assign the Deferred issued by fetch() as a property
        this.deferred = this.fetch();
    }
});
```

**2)** Modify your `updateStats`/`formatChannels` logic to create an array of ids and pass those through your fetch to get a complete data set. This will save tons of time by reducing the number of calls you have to make

```
initialize: function() {
    // other stuff here...
    this.modelChannelList.deferred.done(function(model) {
        model.set();
        view.formatChannelIds();
    });
    // other stuff here...
}

formatChannelIds: function() {
    var _this = this,
        ids = [];

    _.filter(_this.modelChannelList.toJSON(), function(channelObj) {
        if (channelObj['isactive'] == true) {
            ids.push(channelObj['id']);
        }
        _this.updateStats(ids);
    });
}
```

You will have to change up your data service a bit, but this is a change that is ultimately necessary anyways.

Comment: It works fine though i need to run the same number of requests cannot alter my service for now so have done this.